# Can I raise the specificity level of ReturnType?

Tags: typescript

In the below code, `myType` is set to `{ type: string; count: number }`.

I want it to be more specific: `{ type: 'A', count: 5 }`. Is there a way to tell ReturnType to do that?

```js
const myFunction = () => ({type: 'A', count: 5});

type myType = ReturnType<typeof myFunction>;
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it on the `ReturnType` side, because the type is already inferred when you declare a function (effectively: those details are lost). Would `const myFunction = () => ({type: 'A', count: 5} as const);` do for you?

Comment: @zerkms That solves it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it on `ReturnType<T>` side, because at that point the type of the `myFunction` is already inferred and those details are effectively lost.

Alternatively it's possible to use `as const`: it would instruct the compiler to infer as specific type as possible:

```
const myFunction = () => ({type: 'A', count: 5} as const);

type myType = ReturnType<typeof myFunction>;
```

References:

- [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)